# Effectiveness of Landau's Prime Ideal Theorem

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Is Landau's Prime Ideal Theorem effective? It seems clear that bounds of the strongest kind known on the error term cannot be made fully effective, due to the possibility of Siegel zeroes. At the same time, it seems hard to believe that an effective version in the style of Page's theorem on the prime numbers within $[1,x]$ in arithmetic progressions of length $\ll (\log x)^{2-\epsilon}$ isn't possible.

I am asking for an effective proof of the asymptotic statement, not, as I've just said, of the best known error term.

Comment: You need effective bounds $|\zeta_K(1+it)| \ge A_K \log^{-1}(2+|t|)$, $|\zeta_K'(s)| \le B_K \log(2+|t|)^{c_K}$ for $\Re(s) > 1-\frac{d_K}{\log(2+|t|)}$ from which you obtain $|\zeta_K(s)|\ge E_K \log(2+|t|)^{-f_K} $ for $\Re(s) > 1-\frac{g_K}{\log^{h_K}(2+|t|)}$. There you can apply the [usual method](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/ant/main5.pdf) for the PNT. You can look into Iwaniec-Kowalski they should give an effective PNT for most L-functions.

Comment: I see that the crucial statement is Theorem 5.35 in Iwaniec-Kowalski, which states that the only exceptional zeroes there can be for Grossencharakters are  Siegel zeroes of quadratic characters. The usual bounds on such zeroes can be plugged into Theoreö 5.33. It would still be satisfying to have a reference to a self-contained statement that would be completely clear to the non-specialist.